# Twitter API 1.1: Getting friends list from twitter

Tags: twitter

How can I get all followers(friends) of a user who is authenticated by my twitter app. I had tried below one as per twitter docs

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=<user_screen_name>
```

But the result was:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call needs to be made with oAuth, a plain URL call won't work, even if the screen name has authorised your Twitter app.

You need to construct an HTTP GET to the URL you have shown, but with a properly formed authorisation header (oAuth).

It is effectively a web request header with a key of "Authorization" and a generated value which looks like this:

```
OAuth realm="<name of realm, e.g. Twitter API>",
oauth_consumer_key="<your app key, you'll know this already from your twitter app>",
oauth_nonce="<this is basically a random alphanumeric string which your app should generate>",
oauth_timestamp="<number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="<this is the trickiest part, you basically have to hash the request + two secret params through a signing algorithm using the signature method above>"
```

See here for more info:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request